# How can I open an Access DB via ADO so that I can write, but others can only read?

Tags: ms-access, ado

From the documentation, I would expect adModeShareDenyWrite to be the way, but it's not working right.

I'm using an Access database via ADO.   My connection string says Mode=8, which is adModeShareDenyWrite.   But when I try to delete a row from a table, I get:

Unspecified error, Description:Could not delete from specified tables., Source:Microsoft JET Database Engine

In other words, the setting is preventing ME from updating the database using my OWN connection.

I found a couple other posts on the web reporting the same thing, the adModeShareDenyWrite setting used with Access not working as documented.

I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve an administrator changing permissions.  It needs to be something that my program can control.

My motivation here is to minimize the chances of database corruption.  One of the causes of mdb file corruption documented by Microsoft is two apps writing to the same db.   So, I want to make sure that only one app can have a write connection to the db.   Others can read, but should fail when they try to write.   Whoever makes a connection first wins.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Access DB or ADO but isn't it just a single user file/program? Where do the 'others' come in? How do you determine who 'you' are?

Comment: You can have multiple users, and they have a security system (but I don't know the answer to the question).

Comment: I'm hoping for an answer that sticks to my ADO connection string, specifically Mode.

Comment: How do you connect to your Access file? What is your client interface made of? are your computers part of a workgroup? a domain?

Comment: ADO, no network issues.  mdb file is on same box as app that connects via ADO.

Comment: If you can't get ADO to work, is there some reason you're not willing to try DAO?

Comment: 1) I have an ADO dependent codebase.  Not interested in switching.

2) MS docs say DAO is dead/dying (and I've read your comments 
elsewhere here about that)

3) Are you saying, that with DAO, things would work?  I can't trust docs, because according to ADO docs, things should work.  But they don't.

Comment: So you have one machine with the client and the data on it. You want the data to know who is working on the data to see if it can allow its updating. How do people connect to the machine? Do they have a profile? username? a password? How do people start the client? Do they have a username?

Comment: My app opens the database.  While my app has it, I don't want a user to be able to open up the database using other apps, including MS Access itself. Obviously, I can't control Access. adModeShareDenyWrite does prevent access from opening the db, but it prevents me from being able to update it too.

Comment: I am sorry Corey but if you don't answer my questions I cannot find the right solution. And how can you have another user opening the database when the app and the database are on the same machine and and the app has already started ... there is something I do not get!

Comment: Imagine just ONE user, ONE machine, but MULTIPLE apps.   I start up app #1 which grabs the database and then I, on the same machine, start up app #2 which also tries to grab the database.  I want the first one to grab it to win, and the next one to try to grab it to fail.

Comment: ok. code your connection in app#1 with an updatable ADO connection, and code your connection in app#2 with a read-only connection!

Comment: Philippe.  Each app needs to do updates.  I want the first one in to win, and the next one in to be denied.   Either one can be the first one in.

Comment: See last edit on my answer. I did not like it anyway.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164792/how-can-i-open-an-access-db-via-ado-so-that-i-can-write-but-others-can-only-read#164900

Comment: Philippe - I understand the edit of your previous answer.   I appreciate your suggestions.   Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Cory Trager wrote:

> My motivation here is to minimize the
>   chances of database corruption. One of
>   the causes of mdb file corruption
>   documented by Microsoft is two apps
>   writing to the same db. So, I want to
>   make sure that only one app can have a
>   write connection to the db. Others can
>   read, but should fail when they try to
>   write. Whoever makes a connection
>   first wins.

Why are you worrying about it? Jet is by default a multi-user database engine. If somebody else is updating a table, the data pages involved will be locked as read-only (in the state they were before the write began).

There is no realistic reason to fear corruption from mere multi-user interaction. Corruption of Jet databases usually happens because of dropped connections or an interruption of the connection during a write (such as users who force quit an app that is not responding as fast as they want).

I think your fear of corruption is misplaced.

On the other hand, you should still be able to open with an exclusive lock, and I'm not sure why it's not working. Have you considered using DAO instead of ADO to manipulate Jet data? Given that it's the native data interface (instead of a generic interface layer), it ought to be easier.

Comment: What you are saying conflicts with Microsoft's own kb articles

Comment: Which ones? And why do you believe that MS KB articles are without error? There are plenty of them that are misleading and reflect old political conflicts. Just about anything about ADO and Jet is going to be unfair to Jet because it's part of the war on DAO/Jet from c. 2000.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to give them access to a copy of the database. They can change whatever they want, but it won't keep past your copying it over with the master.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I added more to my question to clarify what I'm hoping to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you access here an MDB file from a client interface, whatever it is, and others can also connect to the same file at the same time. When you use adModeShareDenyWrite in your connection mode, it means that you can still share the data with others (no locks of any kind on tables or records in the MDB file) but it can't be modified (this is why you get an error).

One solution would be to manage your connection parameters, with something like that:

```
(where you have a user object with a '.role' property, or anything equivalent ...)
if activeUser.role = "admin" then
    m_connectionMode = adModeWrite
else
    m_connectionMode = adModeShareDenyWrite
endif
```

Then you can open your ADO connection with the parameter m_connectionMode. Administrators will be given the right to insert/update/delete while other users will ony be able to view the data. This means you have somewhere in your program, or ideally in a table, some data saying who is what in your application.

EDIT: Following multiples comments with Corey:

You won't be able to do what you want to do in a straight way. My proposal: when the app accesses the database, it checks for a special file in the .mdb folder (whatever the file is).

If this file exists, the app opens a "read-only" connection.

If this file does not exist, the app creates the file (you can create one for example with "transferDatabase") and open a read-write connection. Once you quit the app, destroy the file.

Comment: adModeShareDenyWrite is not working for me.  It denies me the ability to write ON MY OWN CONNECTION.

Comment: What I am saying is that you'll write a piece of code in your user interface telling the machine to open a "write" connection when the user is Corey Trager (testing on the username of the computer for example), and a "read" connection when it is somebody else.

Comment: I'm not explaining things well.  I'll add more to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Corey Trager wrote:

> I am looking for a solution that
>   doesn't involve an administrator
>   changing permissions. It needs to be
>   something that my program can control.

Well, if the problem is due to NTFS permissions being read-only for the user, there isn't a thing you can do to make the MDB writable. You don't specify where the MDB is stored, on a server or on a local hard drive, but in either case, for a user to have WRITE permissions on the MDB, NTFS permissions have to be set to allow it (for a share on a server, it has to be allowed both on the SHARE and on the underlying file). If it's a local file, the best solution is to make sure that you're storing the file in a location in which user-level logons have full WRITE permission. This would be anywhere in the user profile, and just about nowhere else.

That said, I'm not really suggesting that this is the source of your problem (I really can't say one way or the other), just pointing out that if it *is* the cause, then there's not a damned thing you can do programmatically to work around it.

Comment: I added more to my question to clarify what I'm hoping to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple users connecting to an access database across a network you might want to consider upgrading to SqlServer instead of using Access.